# Need many to many relationship for multiple properties on one entity EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an entity for `Users` and an entity for `Projects`.

I need to be able to assign multiple users to 3 different list properties on my project entity.  I have been able to do this successfully for one property (the many to many relationship) by a join entity.  I could specify the `UserType` on the Users table and just use the one property, but I may run into scenarios where Users may perform more than one role (type) and then that wouldn't work.

I thought I could just put the `UserType` on the join table (entity) but I'm at a loss as to how to build that entity in my DBContext.

Here is what I have that's working with one property defined:

ProjectEntity:

```
public class Project : IInt32Identity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool ProjectActive { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectFile> ProjectFiles { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectUsers> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

UserEntity:

```
public class User : IInt32Identity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<ProjectUsers> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
    public DateTime UserCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UserLastLoggedInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UserModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

JoinEntity:

```
public class ProjectUsers
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

And my `OnModelCreating()` in my DBContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.UserId, bc.ProjectId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.User)
            .WithMany(b => b.ProjectUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Project)
            .WithMany(c => c.ProjectUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProjectId);
    }
```

That all works fine as I said above, but here's what I would like:

ProjectEntity:

```
public class Project : IInt32Identity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool ProjectActive { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectFile> ProjectFiles { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectUsers> ProjectClients { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectUsers> ProjectBuilders { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectUsers> ProjectDesigners { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

UserEntity is the same.

JoinEntity:

```
public class ProjectUsers
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Where I'm lost is on the `OnModelBinding()` code and I'm also not sure if EF would be smart enough to populate the lists correctly based on that `UserType` meta property.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might seem possible to treat `ProjectUser` as the base class/entity, and create different class/entity/type for `ProjectClient`, `ProjectBuilder` and `ProjectDesigner` that are inherited from `ProjectUser`. And then you create tables for each type and *one-to-many* relationship to the project. This is typically called *Table Per Type (TPT)* approach.

However, *TPT* is not yet implemented in EF Core.

You can still achieve it using *Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)*, but you will have just one list in the project for all project users, where `UserId`, `ProjectId` and `UserType` become the complex key. Project clients, builders and designers will be calculated properties off that one project user list.

#### Entities

```cs
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectUser> ProjectUsers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProjectUser> ProjectClients => this.ProjectUsers
        .Where(x => x.UserType == "Client");
    public IEnumerable<ProjectUser> ProjectBuilders => this.ProjectUsers
        .Where(x => x.UserType == "Builder");
    public IEnumerable<ProjectUser> ProjectDesigners => this.ProjectUsers
        .Where(x => x.UserType == "Designer");
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectUser> UserProjects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }
}
```

#### Configurations

```cs
public class ProjectConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();

        builder.Ignore(x => x.ProjectBuilders);
        builder.Ignore(x => x.ProjectClients);
        builder.Ignore(x => x.ProjectDesigners);

        builder.ToTable("Project");
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();

        builder.ToTable("User");
    }
}

public class ProjectUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProjectUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.UserId, x.UserType });
        builder.Property(x => x.UserType).IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Project)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserProjects)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }
}
```

The `virtual` keyword is there for lazy loading support. If you're not doing lazy loading, you don't have to have `virtual` there. Also you have to `[NotMapped]` those 3 calculated properties, which is the same as using `.Ignore` in fluent API's speaking.

#### DbContext

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProjectConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProjectUserConfiguration());
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DL.SO.ProjectUsersDemo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;");
    }
}
```

Nothing special here. After you add the migration and update the database, yours should look like

[image]

After seeding the database with sample data, although it's hard to show here, you can see those 3 lists are filled with correct data:

[image]

Comment: Wow.  Awesome answer.  Thanks so much.  I got pulled away to another project temporarily but this almost all makes sense and seems like it should so I'm gonna mark it as the answer.  I'll try plugging it all in soon.  Question though (sorry to piggy back here, but it's related).  To query this by project, would I use somethinglike this? `return _context.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.ProjectUsers).ThenInclude(b => b.User).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: If you're not doing lazy loading like how my example has setup, then yes you need to do `Include`. And if the id is expected to have one result back, I would do something like `return _context.Projects.Include(x => x.ProjectUsers).ThenInclude(b => b.User).Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();`. If you already turn on lazy loading, you don't need to do any of those includes. Just do something like `return _context.Projects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);`.